# Recursive Makefile - Passing Variables to the Root Makefile

Tags: variables, recursion, linker, makefile

Currently i am having problems with a makefile due to some unexpected recursion and the neccessary collection of filenames. I want to call recursively a Makefile in the root folder of my project and that one should go through every possible subfolder (and their subfolders...) with the goal to collect all files and write them to a variable to be used as "targets" or dependent files.

For example: `/Makefile` goes through `/Source`, `/Source/Boot` and finds `/Source/Boot/Boot.s` (-> one target is therefore `/Source/Boot/Boot.o`) and it goes on with `/Source/Kernel` and finds `/Source/Kernel/Foo.c` (-> second target is therefore `/Source/Kernel/Foo.o`). I can compile these files in the Makefiles in the subfolders, but i need to link them when my root Makefile returns to the root.

So the question is, how can i pass adequately the paths to these object files to the root makefile to link them?

Comment: See http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/ and start by not having recursive makefiles

Comment: @Mark: Any idea how i could solve this more appropriately?

Comment: @Mark, seems like a bad link.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Yes A copy seems to be at http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively called makefiles can't pass info back to their caller (unless you resort to a hack, like using external files to collect the object file names).
Have a look at the paper Mark linked to. It shows a way of organising your project to do what you want, in a maintainable way.